# lnk2001 error - unresolved externals (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, linker-errors, lnk2001

This is going to be tricky because I can't post any real code, but here goes:

I have inheritances in the form A->B->C, where C is the class I'm writing that inherits from B, B inherits from A. A and B were both written by other people and I can't change them (they appear to work standalone). I also have a TestC class, which #includes C.h because it creates an object with which to test; C class is empty, TestC only creates a C object. When I build my TestC project in Visual Studio 2013, I get lnk2001 errors; these go away if I comment out the #include C.h. The C project compiles without issue.

```
A.h
#pragma once
class A {
    public:
        A() {};
        virtual ~A() {};
        virtual int SomeGoodFunction() {return 0;};
        virtual int BadFunction() {return 0;}; //lnk 2001: unresolved external
    private:
        virtual int SomeOtherFunction() {};
        virtual int SomeOtherBadFunction() {}; //lnk 2001: unresolved external
};

B.h
#pragma once
namespace Model {
#include "A.h"
class B : public A {
    public:
        B() {}; //lnk 2019: unresolved external referenced in C()
        virtual ~B() {}; //lnk 2019: unresolved external referenced in ~C()
    private:
        void Bad() {}; //lnk 2001: unresolved external
        virtual ThisFunctionWorks() {};
        void SoDoesThis() {};
};}

C.h
#pragma once
#include "B.h"
class C : public B {
    friend class TestC;
    public:
        C() {};
        ~C() {};
        int Initialize() {};
};

TestC.h
#pragma once
#include "C.h"
namespace Model {
class TestC {
    int Test();
};
}

TestC.cpp
#pragma once
#include "TestC.h"
namespace Model {
int TestC::Test() {
    C test = C(); //if I comment out, builds just fine
    return 0;
}
}
```

(A.h & B.h have corresponding .cpp's where things are defined, but the contents aren't relevant, I don't think; every function that it's complaining about has been defined in the .cpp (I can click 'view definition' and VS will jump to it. Please pardon any syntax errors; I wrote this as psuedo code and since I'm getting linker errors after compiling syntax, I'm pretty sure they don't exist in the original code.)

The lnk2001 errors are saying they can't find the definition of virtual functions in A.h and can't find the constructor, deconstructor, and one function (non-virtual) of B.h. I can open A & B's .h/.cpp files and see the functions it's complaining about being defined. TestC's include directories has these included (and I can open them by clicking on the #includes, so it's working). Project dependencies are set for build order. From a programming standpoint, C doesn't really NEED to inherit from B, but the higher ups made the decision and my peon self can't change it. I'm guessing it has to do with some nuance of inheritance and/or virtual functions that I'm not aware of.

What am I missing? I feel like I've gone through most Stack Overflow articles...

EDIT: Each of these are in their own projects, with everything except TestC being a .lib, TestC is a .exe. When I use this basic code all in the same project, it compiles with no errors, so I'm thinking it's an issue between the C & TestC project.

Comment: So have you defined those functions? The contents of the source files are very relevant, since you seem to be missing definitions that should be in those files.

Comment: Also, how are you declaring a constructor `A()` in class `B`? Please post code that compiles (apart from the errors you're asking about).

Comment: Every function that it is complaining about is defined in the class's corresponding .cpp, but it's complicated code that I'm not allowed to post for security reasons. As for the constructor issue, that was a typo from copy/pasting. My apologies.

Comment: If the functions really are defined (and you're linking with the files that defined them) then it's hard to guess what the problem might be. Can you add enough code to what you've posted to make a complete test case - that is, one which reproduces the link error you're seeing, even though all the functions have definitions?

Comment: Are any of your real classes templates? If so, your answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021

Comment: None of them are templated, but there are some namespaces involved. I edited the psuedocode to show that; I'm working on throwing together basic code that will replicate it.

Comment: How do you know that the .cpp files in question are really used by the linker? Look at your link command in project properties.

Comment: @n.m. : how do you recommend I do that? When I go into Properties > Linker > Commandline, I don't see anything listed.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't indeed list the object files, only the flags. Look at the linker log in the build folder instead (a file called something like "link.command.1.tlog")